# Disable certain emails in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, environment

I would like to turn off certain emails in development and on test/staging servers, but keep sending them in production.  What I currently do is set the default "to" address for these administrative mails to blank:

```
  default :to => Rails.env.production? ? "admin-list@sharethevisit.com" : ""
```

However, this puts stack traces in my development log when I'm testing the user mails which should be sending.

Is there a more effective way of disabling certain emails based on the current environment?  I tried checking in the functions themselves, but is not ideal because I have to change each function, plus it doesn't actually work... it just fails to set the needed @account variable before rendering the email and creating a different stack trace.

```
  def user_registered_notify_email(account)
    if Rails.env.production?
      @account = account
      mail(:subject => "New user registered: #{@account.full_name}")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use mail interceptors as described here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Comment: Oh that looks so useful. Somehow I missed that asciicast!

Comment: http://asciicasts.com/  is now "Online Marketing for Yellow Gold Karat Fine Jewelry"

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I found this to credit the author but this is how I redirected email in development mode.  Create a new file in RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers for this.  DEFAULT_DEV_EMAIL_OVERRIDE is defined in our main site config with other static values.

```
if Rails.env.development?
  if Rails.version =~ /^2\./
    class ActionMailer::Base
      def create_mail_with_overriding_recipients
        mail = create_mail_without_overriding_recipients
        mail.to = DEFAULT_DEV_EMAIL_OVERRIDE
        mail
      end
      alias_method_chain :create_mail, :overriding_recipients
    end
  elsif Rails.version =~ /^3\./
    if Rails.env.development?
      class OverrideMailRecipient
        def self.delivering_email(mail)
          mail.to = DEFAULT_DEV_EMAIL_OVERRIDE
        end
      end
      ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(OverrideMailRecipient)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I suppose the double checking of development mode could be dropped if one were to keep this whole bit of code; we're removing the Rails 2 check from the app once it migrates.

Comment: That looks like it will set the mail.to value to something like "" or "devnull@example.com" ... but the former will cause stack traces (as my existing solution does), and the latter will cause my email provider to send garbage emails, wasting their cycles and my sent items folder.   Or am I missing something about how this will cause the emails not to even be sent?

Comment: I missed maybe an easy way to really address the issue.  Is `ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = false` in development mode?  Btw, I/we chose to leave emailing on in dev so we could see what they actually looked like but they're sent to a single system account.

Comment: I may go with that for the quick and easy fix!  Although I'd like to see delivery errors for the user emails and ignore them for the admin notifications, in theory, I think in practice I just want to ignore delivery errors in dev.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an interceptor to set `Mail::Message#perform_deliveries` to `false`:

```
class NeverDeliverInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.perform_deliveries = false
  end
end

if !Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(NeverDeliverInterceptor)
end
```

[See API doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail%2FMessage%3Aperform_deliveries) for source & other usage.